# triggers in checkout page after review update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using `update_checkout` trigger to do some function when review table is  updated in checkout page. Since so many functions are being hooked to trigger, would like to use some other trigger to hook other functions. I couldn't find any other trigger after review update. Helps are invited. Would like to know available triggers in checkout page.

Comment: I can't find `update_checkout`, can you show us your code?

Comment: it's a trigger in js. I am not having any error. I want some other trigger.

Comment: if you're using `$( document.body ).on( 'update_checkout', fn );` then that would not be a problem.. you just have to put an `if` statement in your `fn`... but if ever you're going to call `$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' )` then that's a problem. You might be calling some unnecessary update...

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any suitable trigger that does same as `update_checkout`.
Thinking, because that would then be redundant.

if your just going to use it as:

```
$( document.body ).on( 'update_checkout', fn );
```

Then that should not be a problem. Just add an `if` statement inside your function `fn` that meets your condition. Like so:

```
fn = function(){
   if (test) {
      // do things if test is true
   }
}
```

However, if your going to call `$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' )`, in hopes of calling your `fn`, then that might be a problem. You might call unnecessary trigger. You just have to call `fn` or create your own trigger and call it whenever you need it and also trigger it inside your `if` statement in your `fn`.

Comment: I think `update_checkout` trigger has a function to execute which is written by woocommerce . When i try to give my function , won't it be an override ?

Comment: no.. all `$( document.body ).on( 'update_checkout', ... );` statements will be called when one calls `$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' )`